# Exponential smoothing method that can be used in seasonal forecasting without trend

Tags: forecasting, seasonality, exponential-smoothing

I'm working on the task of forecasting. The data I have is seasonal. I use exponential smoothing methods, but my references (e.g. for the Holt-Winters method) are for using such methods for seasonal *and* trended data.

Are there exponential smoothing methods for seasonal data without trend? Any references?

Answer (score 3):

There are of course exponential smoothing models with seasonality and without trend. [Gardner's "Exponential Smoothing - The state of the art part II" (2006)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169207006000392) is a very good overview article. You may also want to look at ["Exponential Smoothing - The State Space Approach" by Hyndman et al.](http://exponentialsmoothing.net/), or [this free online forecasting textbook](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/).

In R, you can use the `ets()` command in the `forecast` package and specify `model="ZNZ"` to suppress trend but allow `ets()` to fit seasonality, if it is there.

For example, here is your result if you forecast monthly airline passengers including seasonality but excluding trend:

```
library(forecast)
?ets
plot(forecast(ets(AirPassengers,model="ZNZ")))
```

[image: airpassengers]